# I have to make an article with lms.cls but I am not able to proceed as there is the error "lms.cls does not exist"

Tags: errors

I have to make an article with `lms.cls`. But I am not able to proceed, as there is error when compiling which is “`lms.cls` does not exist”.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `lms` class is not included in the main TeX distribution; you can download it from http://www.lms.ac.uk/publication/au-instructions#LaTeX

Answer (score 3):

The document class of [London Mathematical Society](http://www.lms.ac.uk/) `lms` isn't available at CTAN and so it can't be part of any TeX distribution. However you can download the document class at the website of London Mathematical Society: [lms.cls](http://www.lms.ac.uk/publications/au-instructions#LaTeX)

After downloading you can either put the files in your working directory or install them in your local texmf-tree as e.g. described here: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)